# Best shoes for a boom-op?

Tags: boom-operator

Hello!

Just wondering what peoples' preferences are to footwear while booming in the studio? I currently use sports canvas trainers (or sneakers to all you across the pond), which don't squeak, are dark coloured, but can make my feet a little achey at the end of a long day.

I was thinking in investing in some walking trainers, or some sketchers which seem to offer more support for people being up on their feet all day. Another post mentioned climbing shoes to use while booming. Anyone have any other recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.props-n-frocks.co.uk/prodimages/accessories/boots/XMS093.jpg

Comment: @James do you really use these? You must use a fisher boom then! :P

Comment: When appropriate, I prefer these http://www.digitaldeliftp.com/DigitalDeliToo/Images/BIndleStiff.png

Answer (score 3):

Walking style shoes are the best in my opinion, they cushion your soles and support your foot when you are standing for long periods of time. I have a great pair of North Face which are also breathable, not waterproof, but would be perfect for indoor studio work.

I recommend having another pair of shoes that you can wear then not booming so you are not in the same shoes all day long. I have a pair of Crocs that I slip into when there is a break.

Comment: @SiAudio Haha I was waiting for someone to say crocs!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter what shoes you have as long as you're comfortable in 'em and they're noiseless, but some people I know uses Ecco-shoes for extended periods of time with good results. Myself I have a taste for heavy boots, so when actually wearing shoes on interior settings and studios I use either Dr Martens, Gettagrip, of Underground. Simple models with steel-toe but no loose rattling metal, chains or zippers. As they all have rubber soles I can walk completely silently with 'em, and they have an amazing fit...when walked in, that is...

I do, however, often go bare-foot or in soft cotton socks indoors for a good feel of the surroundings, unless of course I expect there to be broken glass or nail or something...or the carpet is so disgusting you would rather take a bullet to your most precious parts than let a single bare cell on your body touch it (don't ask). As I can't very well look where I'm going while booming i can at least feel my way ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with choosing shoes for booming and i know that sneakers can be pretty cheap but have you ever thought about service shoes? My girlfriend has a pair of black no slip shoes for her restaurant job that are rated at 10 hours and I know if you spend more you can get longer rated shoes.  She brings them to work and puts them on there so that they will be comfortable longer into the work day. I think hers are Keens.

Answer (score 0):

I always use a pair of classic, slip-on Vans. I find them really comfortable and quiet as well. And I can easily take them off and on if ever I need to for locations that have, for example, uncontrollably noisy, boomy, wooden floors.

But of course it also depends on your needs. I wouldn't use these shoes if I had to shoot in a sewer like Dirty Jobs or something.

Answer (score 0):

I use a pair of Timberland Gortex shoes. You never know when you're gonna suddenly step into a puddle of water or some unstable ground.

Answer (score 0):

Anything as long as they are comfortable, silent and discrete.

Answer (score 0):

First check out your video monitor to find out what part of the floor the camera will see. Then use a piece, or several pieces, of carpet and gaffer them to the floor (or ask your assistant to do so). This way you don't just damp your footsteps but the footsteps of the entire crew and offscreen cast. 
I've been using this method for several productions now and it comes in very handy, it makes your production-sound a lot cleaner and makes it better possible to make useable MS recordings, since the atmosphere of the room is more clear. 
Watch out with taking your shoes of, even on fiction film sets. All the heavy stuff laying there makes it easy to break a tow, and then you'll be out of work for a couple of weeks.

For documentary and fiction film sets I will usually wear Clark Desert Boots, they are silent, good shoes for interior and exterior and you can wear them from a lunch in jail to a weddingparty in the hilton.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a camera P.A. on set, lots of walking around and standing, and I've been having similar issues with me feet. I noticed damn near everyone on the set wears either Merrell's or New Balance, including the Boom Operators. And I couldn't find a pair of New Balance in my size so I bought a pair of Merrel's, and they are so comfortable its amazing. I went to Zappo's and bought a pair of New Balance though, because I want to be able to switch out my shoes. The Merrell's are kind of warm, and they're midsize, I wanted the more breathable lightweight Merrell's, but again nothing in my size. But I wasn't going to go another day with my feet kiling me like that so I got the midsize pair. And I haven't heard any kind of squeaking or noise when I walk either.